# Modifying library function after importing

Tags: python

Say I'm importing a library which has some core functionality for the program I'm writing. It looks like:

```
class dothing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # stuff

    def main(self):
        self.thing = []
        self.option = []
```

How can I modify the contents of its variables, without touching the library itself - in other words, from my local code. Or, how can I modify the function "main"?

I've heard of "monkey patching" but I'm not sure this is the right thing

Comment: Provide a more complete example to show the behavior you intend. At this point, it's unclear what your *specific* question is.

Comment: Does inheriting from your "dothing" class, and overriding the "main" method, answer what you need ?

Comment: @ma3oun precisely

Comment: @popopret Has your question been sufficiently addressed? If so, you should mark the best answer using the checkmark beside it. Otherwise, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alter the `main` function, you can indeed use monkey patching. This is the preferred strategy if you want to alter how the whole class `donothing` behaves.

```
class dothing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # stuff

    def main(self):
        self.thing = []
        self.option = []

def my_new_main(self):
    print("Hello")
    self.thing = {}
    self.option = ["Foo"]

donothing.main = my_new_main

dn = donothing()
dn.main()
# Hello
dn.thing
# {}
dn.option
# ["Foo"]
```

You can also use this strategy to attach new methods to `donothing`.

```
donothing.bar = lambda self, x: x + 3
dn.bar(1)
# 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Define another class that inherits from your original class and override the "main" method as follows:

```
class doOtherThing(dothing):
  def main(self):
    self.thing = [1] # this is just a value different from [] in the original "main"
```